# Solving error "Stack overflow in regexp matcher" when starting eshell

Tags: regex, emacs, eshell

I recently solved an irritating error I suddenly started getting upon starting an emacs eshell: the message "Stack overflow in regexp matcher" would appear in the echo area and my eshell session would start without a prompt.  The shell would be active but the cursor would appear only on the far left with no sort of path or time decoration that was in my normal prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to figure out that the error was coming from the eshell startup reading the eshell history file, causing a regexp to puke from something there.  The solution is to remove the contents of that file which may be found by entering this command:

```
(print eshell-history-file-name)
```

in, e.g., an eshell session or wherever one can evaluate an emacs lisp expression.

Comment: Seems like a workaround rather than a solution.  Why did that file's content cause Eshell to signal a stack overflow?  Please add the details to your *question*.